# File name with special character "^" unrecognized by pattern.match (RegEx function)

Tags: python, regex, utf-8

I'm working with Python 3.6.5 on a Winows 10.

I can not verify if a file exists in a directory or not.
The problem seems to come from the special character "^".

When I run the code below, the "WITHOUT_CIRCUMFLEX" and "^WITH_CIRCUMFLEX" files are well listed by the os.listdir () function.
However, the file "^ WITH_CIRCUMFLEX" is not recognized by the function pattern.match (file) ... while it exists!

Would anyone have an idea to solve this problem?
Thanks for your help

```
# coding: utf-8
```

import pandas as pd
import os.path
import regex
path = "C:\Users\David\test"
list_name = ['WITHOUT_CIRCUMFLEX', '^WITH_CIRCUMFLEX']

df_empty = pd.DataFrame()

for name in list_name:
    df_empty.to_pickle('{path}\{name}.pkl'.format(**locals()))
    pattern = regex.compile('{name}.pkl'.format(**locals()))

`# Check if file already exist
check = False
for file in os.listdir(path):
    print("I found this file\t" + file)
    if pattern.match(file):
        check = True

if check is True:
    print("\t" + name + " file exist" + "\n")
else:
    print("\t" + name + " does not exist")`

Comment: What's the regex module? I think your meaning is `import re`. And `^` is a metacharacter. You have to use `\^`.

Comment: Python has an inbuilt regex module, but the name is "re". to use it, type import re. I have not seen the import regex statement before.

Comment: `^` is a *regex meta character*, meaning "match at the start of the string". You'd need to escape it if you wanted to use it in a regex.

Comment: Why use a regex for this though? Are you looking for files that end in `{name}.pkl`, or files that consist entirely of `{name}.pkl`? Neither match requires a regex.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh: there are legitimate uses for the [`regex` module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/). I don't see those here, but it could very well be *intentional*.

Comment: @tdh8316: presumably that's the [`regex` module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/).

Comment: Thank you @MartijnPieters Appreciate the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^` is a regex meta character, so it'll not match a literal `^` character in text. You'd need to *escape* such characters:

```
'\^WITH_CIRCUMFLEX'
```

If your inputs are generated or taken from another source, use the `regex.escape()` function to escape meta characters for you:

```
for name in list_name:
    df_empty.to_pickle('{path}\{name}.pkl'.format(**locals()))
    name = regex.escape(name, special_only=True)
    pattern = regex.compile('{name}.pkl'.format(**locals()))
```

However, if you are looking to match files, you currently are not using any of the reasons you'd use a regular expression. Your pattern will at best match any filename that ends with `{name}.pkl`. You'd be much better off using the [glob module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html):

```
import glob

for name in list_name:
    ...
    escaped_name = glob.escape(name)
    files = glob.glob('*{}.pkl'.format(escaped_name))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly with your regex.escape function solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

`^` is a regex metacharacter, so you have to escape it. The easiest way to do this is to use the [`regex.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) function, which automatically escapes metacharacters in an arbitrary string.

So instead of

```
pattern = regex.compile('{name}.pkl'.format(**locals()))
```

use

```
pattern = regex.compile(regex.escape('{name}.pkl').format(**locals()))
```

Comment: `regex` is the next-generation version, installable from PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/regex/

Comment: Not that they are using the features of the library here.

Comment: Didn't know that, I'll change my answer. Thanks!